# Token Mismatch Exception on Login (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I followed [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authentication-with-laravel-4--net-35593) tutorial on creating a registration and login page using Laravel.

Everything works smoothly, the only issue is that I am unable to Login. If I provide the wrong username/password, it correctly gives me an error message. But if I use the right credentials, I get the following error -

```
Illuminate \ Session \ TokenMismatchException
```

This is my (default) csrf function -

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

This is the form action -

```
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'signin', 'class'=>'form-signin')) }}
```

And this is the relevant portion of my UsersController

```
public function __construct() {
$this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
$this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only'=>array('getDashboard')));

}
public function postSignin() {
       if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {
            return Redirect::to('dashboard')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('login')
            ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
            ->withInput();
    }  
}

public function getDashboard() {
    $this->layout->content = View::make('users.dashboard');
}
```

Comment: Try to `dd(Session::token();` and `dd(Input::get('_token')` in CSRF filter to check which part is missing Token.

Comment: Issue randomly rectified itself... O.o

Comment: Have you added this line in your form?
`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />`

Answer (score 4):

Laravel makes a quite esoteric use of sessions, and when the user cookie and the user salt in stored in the database disalign for some reason (for example, when you re-seed your user table), you get a Token Mismatch Exception without further explanation.

If that's the case, just delete your cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on login also. From time to time this exception occurred so I stop and tried to reproduce it. I succeed by doing this:

First I load the login page.

Then I deleted the cookies.

Then, without reloading the login page, I entered username and password and tried to login.

Because session was deleted (when I deleted the cookies), it was normal that this code was not going to pass and it will throw the TokenMismatchException.

```
Route::filter('csrf', function() {
    if ( Session::getToken() != Input::get('_token')) {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

So, what I've done to solve my problem was to add a redirect to login page with a message to inform the user that the session might expired.

```
Route::filter('csrf', function() {
    if ( Session::getToken() != Input::get('_token')) {
        return Redirect::to('/admin/login')->with('warning', 'Your session has expired. Please try logging in again.');
    }
});
```

Thus, after page reloading, a new session is created and the problem is solved.

Comment: Do you mean to add `Route::filter` in my `web.php` I am `laravel 5.4`

Answer (score 1):

/config/session.php
set that info 'expire_on_close' => true, save and load again ur site you wont get anymore the issue with Token Mismatch Exception on Login

Answer (score 1):

Check your route:list to see if Login is protected by web middleware. In my case, I made mistake by adding web middileware to login route where it should be guest middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, it was caused by no free disk space.

Get some space and try to login again.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` to help clarify the error for the end-user, in addition to setting session to expire on close, as mentioned in this thread.

```php
    protected function prepareException(Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
            return new HttpException(
                419,
                "{$exception->getMessage()}. Please clear your browser cookies and try again.",
                $exception
            );
        }

        return parent::prepareException($exception);
    }
```