# Login into laravel 5.2 from other domain

Tags: c#, .net, laravel, laravel-5

I have a project with **laravel 5.2**. There is **another system in .net**. What I want is to get **login into laravel 5.2 from .net system**. For that, I'm **making ajax call** from .net app to laravel app. But laravel app is throwing `TokenMismatchException`. I know I have to send csrf token in request. But **how to send csrf token from .net app**. If anyone knows the answer, it will be appreciated.

Here is my code.

**.net app**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://192.168.1.78/laravel-project/login',
    data: {
        email: 'xyz@xyz.com',
        password: 'pass'
    }
}).success(function (response) {
    response = $.parseJSON(response);
}).error(function () {
    alert('error');
});
```

Comment: Have two choice at here: 1. Disable CSRF Token - 2. Make one API for login: by JWTAuth or something like that.

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn, I can go for choice 1. But I can disable it only for login request. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the csrf check on the login uri by editing the `VerifyCsrfToken` class of your Laravel app:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'login/*', // Your route url here
    ];
}
```

This will make the ajax call to the login route vulnerable to csrf-attacks, but will solve your problem. See it as a workaround / quick fix.

What you **really** want to do, is to provide the login via an api-call. Since you are using another app to access the laravel app. This is what API's are meant to be used for.

Laravel routes are default handled by the `web` middleware group, which includes the `VerifyCsrfToken` class.

What you want to do is specify a new middleware group for you api-calls, which does not include any csrf-checks. I would consider using a package for this, e.g. https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth

Comment: It didn't work. I'm getting empty array of `$this->except`.

Comment: I dont understand. Do you get an error message or an exception is thrown?

Comment: sorry, I'm getting exception.

Comment: Did you specify the correct url? try replacing `login/*` with `login`

Comment: I have already tried. I think I have to setup except from some else class.

Comment: Check which class is used in Kernel.php. This is the default: `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125409/discussion-between-akshay-vaghasiya-and-henrik).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send more information with javascript try this

```
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://192.168.1.78/myproject/login',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: dataType,
        data: data,
        crossDomain: true,
        cotentType: YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE,
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback,
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', SOMETHING.val());
        }
    });
```

To make this script right for your needs, you should read about **CORS**,  **crossDomain** and **xhr.setRequestHeader**

You can also use Postman  (Chrome extension)

[xhr.setRequestHeader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms536752(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Postman sample](http://www.java-success.com/chrome-postman-to-test-and-debug-restful-web-services/)

***EDIT***: Did you read this? [Token Mismatch Exception on Login (Laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22066241/token-mismatch-exception-on-login-laravel)

Regards,

Comment: Above code is still throwing same error. And you have talked about CORS. For that, I have tried
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cros-access-control-allow-origin-not-in-the-headers

Comment: I have also tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748981/laravel-5-2-cors-get-not-working-with-preflight-options

Comment: I adited my answer with a new link.

Comment: thanx for refereence. In the link, there is a laravel app. But in my case, how .net app will get token and pass it to me?.

Comment: I did not use laravel, but I had to send tokens, JWT token, I used  xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', TOKENVALUE);

Do you know where your token is by now? in C#? If yes, use an hidden field to send the token value to the view, then read it with your JS code.

Comment: exactly. I don't know where is my token in C#. can you suggest me how to get it?